# Reading multiple text files and listing contents vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

The code below basically lists all of the text files in a folder

```
Private zMailbox As String = "c:\testfolder\"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim finfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo(zMailbox)
    For Each fi In finfo.GetFiles("*.txt")
        ListBox1.Items.Add(fi.FullName) 'full path only
    Next
End Sub
```

What I really need to do is use the `ReadAllLines` method and populate the `ListBox` with the contents - this is where I'm getting stuck.  Any advice?

Comment: you want to fill a single listbox with the contents of multiple files?  open them one by one, readalllines and add them

Comment: Actually no, I want to do is add the details to an array so i can then do a lookup for certain values. Adding them to the listbox would just be an easier way of me trying to work it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add each line in the text file as a separate item in the `ListBox`, you can use the `ListBox.Items.AddRange` method to add all of the lines in one method call, like this:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(fi.FullName))
```

The `AddRange` method allows you to add multiple items at once by giving it an array of the items to add.  Since `ReadAllLines` returns an array of strings, you can just pass that array to the `AddRange` method to add all the lines as individual items.

If it's easier for you to understand what's going on, you can break out the steps into multiple lines, like this:

```
Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(fi.FullName)
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lines)
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks - just what i was looking for to get me going.